# Java REST API: Returning ArrayList<T> as a JSON Response Issue

Tags: java, rest, google-app-engine, arraylist, jersey

I need to simply return an ArrayList of Objects as my Rest API Response but I keep getting this error:

> A message body writer for Java class
>   java.util.Collections$SingletonList and MIME media type
>   application/json was not found.

**My Code:**

```
@Path("/plans")
public class PlanAPI {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/getplans/{type}")
    public Response GetAllPlans(@PathParam("type") String type) {

        PlanDAO dao = new PlanDAO();
        ArrayList<UserPlan> plans = dao.GetAllPlans_ByType(type);

        return Response.status(200).entity(plans).build();
    }
}
```

**The Error I get:**

```
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse logException
SEVERE: Mapped exception to response: 500 (Internal Server Error)
javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: com.sun.jersey.api.MessageException: A message body writer for Java class java.util.Collections$SingletonList, and Java type java.util.List<java.util.ArrayList<com.dinuka.planapp.model.UserPlan>>, and MIME media type application/json was not found.

    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.write(ContainerResponse.java:284)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1510)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:558)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:733)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:128)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:98)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:513)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
Caused by: com.sun.jersey.api.MessageException: A message body writer for Java class java.util.Collections$SingletonList, and Java type java.util.List<java.util.ArrayList<com.dinuka.planapp.model.UserPlan>>, and MIME media type application/json was not found.
```

**UserPlan Class:**

```
public class UserPlan {

    String ID = "";
    String Name = "";
    String Description = "";

    //Getter Setter and Constructors
}
```

When I call the API, I get the aforementioned error. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@XmlRootElement 
@XmlType(propOrder = {ID, Name, Description})
public class UserPlan {

String ID = "";
String Name = "";
String Description = "";

//Getter Setter and Constructors
}
```

Try to add  @XmlRootElement @XmlType for UserPlan class

```
String json = new Gson().toJson(plans);

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/getplans/{type}")
public String GetAllPlans(@PathParam("type") String type) {

    PlanDAO dao = new PlanDAO();
    ArrayList<UserPlan> plans = dao.GetAllPlans_ByType(type);

    return new Gson().toJson(plans);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 thing that are wrong with this code :

1. POJO (`UserPlan`) does not correspond to any [built-in provider](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/message-body-workers.html#d0e7796) that jersey support. Typically, a provider(or messagebodyreader/writer) will handle conversion of objects to corresponding MediaType. So, Either [create a Provider](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/message-body-workers.html#d0e6826) for every custom class you define or convert that class to pre-handled type. Adding `@XmlRootElement` annotation for your POJO makes it represent a `JAXBElement`, for which default provider will work.
2. To use generic collection type use:

`ArrayList<UserPlan> plans = dao.GetAllPlans_ByType(type);
 GenericEntity entity = new GenericEntity<List<UserPlan>>(plans) {};
 return Response.ok(entity).build();`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using maven for your project then kindly uncomment following lines from pom.xml file and after that restart your server. It will working fine.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```